Why are there multiple payment addresses associated with a private key?
I use the wallet to generate a receiving address A starting with 3 and temporarily name it "A". I export the private key and temporarily name it "X".
I run the command dumpwallet /Users/my/Desktop/1.txt, then open 1.txt. In 1.txt, I find a receiving address starting with bc1 corresponding to the private key "X".

Why does a private key address correspond to two payment addresses?
In the 1.txt file, the receiving address beginning with 3 is followed by 00...... This code should not be a private key. What is it?


Concerning the output of dumpwallet, this is the best answer:
dumpwallet output documentation & explanation?
About your questions:

Why does a private key address correspond to two payment addresses?

Addresses are instructions from your wallet to the paying wallet.
These instructions are divided in 2 parts: a prefix and some string.
If the prefix is:

"1" this means your wallet wants the receiving coins to be locked in a P2PKH script (Pay To Public Key Hash), and the hash of your public key is the string part of the address;
"3" this means your wallet wants the receiving coins to be locked in a P2SH script (Pay To Script Hash), and the hash of the script is the string part of the address;
"bc1q" this means your wallet wants the receiving coins to be locked in a Segwit script, and the hash of the script is the string part of the address;
"bc1p" this means your wallet wants the receiving coins to be locked in a Taproot script, and the hash of the script is the string part of the address.

So, the same exact private key can originate 4 different addresses.

In the 1.txt file, the receiving address beginning with 3 is followed by 00...... This code should not be a private key. What is it?

It's the P2SH address for that private key.

Taproot scripts contain a tweaked public key, not a hash (though the tweak used is derived from the hash of the (set of) scripts in its script tree).

Also bc1q addresses come in two flavors: P2WPKH (which contain a pubkey hash like P2PKH) and P2WSH (which contain a script hash like P2SH).

Thanks @PieterWuille

A private key "X" can generate multiple address types (legacy and SegWit). So, it’s normal to see it corresponding to both a legacy address (starting with 3) and a SegWit address (starting with bc1).
The address starting with 3 followed by 00 in 1.txt is a P2SH (Pay-to-Script-Hash) address. This isn’t a private key but another type of receiving address format used in Bitcoin transactions.
Hope that clears things up! 
Cheers,
